# How to override the \vec{} command so that we have an underline?

Tags: vector

I have been using the `\vec{}` command for specifying vectors in this paper I am writing, but I would like to denote vectors with just an underline, and I would like to keep using the `\vec{}` command, so that I don't need to change it everywhere.

How can I override `\vec{}` so that I obtain a underline instead of a left-to-right arrow above the letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is really necessary, use a redefinition of `\vec` to apply `\underline`. I am pretty sure, there's a better version of `\underline` in math mode.

**Edit** Another way of `\underline`: Use `\ushortw` from the `ushort` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\renewcommand{\vec}{\underline}


\begin{document}
$\vec{A}$


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand\vec{\underline}` might be better.  This way `#1` doesn't get tokenized twice.

Comment: @HenriMenke what is the potential advantage?

Comment: @HenriMenke, Christian do you know a question about this on TeX.sx? I'm thinking of asking one myself…

Comment: @clemens: No sorry, but Henri seems to have more insight than I have on this